# Add several specification without saving first

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm working on a editing tool (type of a simple CMS) in PHP/MySQL for a product catalog. I have search the Internet for a solution but I don't even know what to search for. So now my hope is on you guys.

I have a form where you can put all kinds of data like part.no, description an so on. All of this data is saved into a MySql table (items). I also have a table with predefined specifications.

What I want to do, and that I can't find a solution for, is to have a dropdown meny (or similar) and a add button to add a row for each related specifications without saving the whole form each time. I want to save first when all specifications is selected.

So, can I use PHP for this or do I need jQuery/Javascript or similar? I know it's possible, have seen it in OpenCart :-)

I hope someone understands my question. It's hard to explane i a language I'm not fully manage.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

**Client-side vs Server-side**

Javascript: This sits in the user's browser. So anything you want to move in the user's browser will be done with JavaScript. This is "client-side"

PHP: This site on the server, so takes inpute from the user's browser and gives back a response (generally HTML, but can also be JSON or XML which is read by Javascript.). This is "server-side".

**Libraries**

jQuery: This is a set of functions written for Javascript to make it easier. So it runs in the user's browser and makes it easier for you to write bits that move on the screen.

You get similar libraries that help you write PHP (commonly called "frameworks") and there are many others for javascript as well.

**Where to start**

1. Write your HTML page as you want it to look. Keep it simple for the first time.
2. Then write some javascript (possibly using jQuery) to move the menu. Google "jquery menu dropdown" or similar and you'll find a solution you cna customise.
3. Then write some PHP that gives you the HTML you wrote in '1'.
4. Then decide what's going to happen when you click on a link in the HTML, and repeat the process (write HTML, incorporate Javascript to make it move, write PHP to give HTML)
5. Then work out which bits of the HTML are common or structured and should come from a database.

Without writing it for you (in which case you'll never learn) best to start one bit at a time and build as your knowledge grows. Bucket loads of examples on the web when youreach a particular problem you need to solve.

---

After comment "[how to] make it possible to select and add single/multiple specifications (from another table) without saving the whole form each time a specs is added":

**Growing with AJAX**

What you are asking is AJAX - this is where you get Javascript to talk to the server, and for javascript to move bits on the page based on the results. jQuery is probably the easiest (and probably has best [documentation / examples](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the ajax, as well as [moving the DOM](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)).

Basically: you have an "event" that you trap in JavaScript, example

```
/// Using jQuery to trap a button click
$().ready( function() {
   $("#ButtonID").click( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('Button Clicked');
   });
});
```

Then you build in an AJAX call inside that event (also check out [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) as the syntax is easier, you just get less control). The AJAX wil send a request to your PHP server, and you can get PHP to return HTML which you can replace/insert using the DOM manipulation functions linked below (e.g. before, html etc) or, when you get more advanced, you'll send back JSON which is a data structure you cna more easily manipulate in JavaScript to stipulate what actions are required.

As above, without actually writing it for you, the best place to start is to read the docs and have a go.  Google "jquery AJAX PHP table example" or similar and you'll find an example somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But you missunderstand me totally. My misstake! I already have a working PHP page to create and edit product items. What I want is to develop it further and make it possible to select and add single/multiple specifications (from another table) without saving the whole form each time a specs is added. I could use a multiple select list for this but I want it to be more visible (and fancier). For example, you select a specs in a dropdown list and hit a add button. Then I want it to add a row and maybe store it in a session cookie or something.

Comment: Thank you! That sounds right. I will give it a go and see if I can make it work. My skills aren't that high but i doesn't usually give up that fast :-)